# Sort array by numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array which I want to sort. Every element has a format like
this: `"5000 name"`. What I want to do is sort it in a descending order, so the results would be something akin to `["5000 person1", "4500 person2", "3000 person3"]`. Is this possible? How should this be approached? Would appreciate some code because I'm pretty confued.

Comment: Have you tried `arr.sort().reverse()` ?

Comment: Are the numbers always 4 digits (or prefixed with leading zeroes)?

Comment: `arr.sort( (a,b) => parseInt( b ) - parseInt( a ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.sort`](http://Array.prototype.sort()) with [`String.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with the `numeric` option:

```js
const data = ["5000 name", "300 name", "10 name", "1000 name"]

const result = data.sort((a,b) => b.localeCompare(a, undefined, {numeric: true}))

console.log(result)
```